# How properly extract substrings from an NSString without hardcoding positions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I have this string returning:

> "Monday thru Friday 8:00 AM - 7:30 PM"

I need to eliminate the mon-fri stuff in order to get this:

> "8:00AM - 7:30PM"

And then I need to split it into opening time and closing time in order to determine if its open or not:

> "8:00AM" && "7:30PM"

But there are a lot of stores and they have different opening and closing times, so I cant just extract 6 characters from 8 or anything like that.

So far I decided to go this route:

```
NSRange startRange = [storeTime.text rangeOfString:@"-"];

NSString *openString = [storeTime.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(16, startRange.location-17)];

NSString *closeString = [storeTime.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location+2, storeTime.text.length-(startRange.location+2))];
```

But it just seems like i could break because of the hardcoded start at 16 and it makes me wonder if it could break anywhere else.  Any better ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a regular expression - see e.g. the NSRegularExpression class.

Comment: What are your possible input formats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the text before the time interval is always in the format `<someday> thru <someday>`, then you can find the index of the first numerical character (digit), and get a substring from that index.

Then, split the time strings on `@" - "` using the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method.

Example:

```
NSString *s = @"monday thru sunday, 0:00 - 23:59";

NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
int idx = [s rangeOfChatacterFromSet:digits].location;
NSString *timeStr = [s substringFromIndex:idx];

NSArray *timeStrings = [timeStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
```

Comment: I think instead of "always in the format ...", you could just say, "If the first digit is always the start of the time" or something similar.

Comment: @MarcusAdams well, technically, yes!

Comment: This digits thing is interesting. Saves a lot of clipping work. And this will work even if the times are not in 24hr format? Because if you noticed, its "7:00 AM - 10:00 PM" for example.  So how would I deal with the AM and PM?  Should I split them and THEN trim off the last 3 characters from each?

Comment: @marciokoko Yes, exactly, but I think you should have a look at either `NSDateFormatter` or the date handling functions in the C standard library for advanced date/time string formatting.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` to grab the two time strings out of a string:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
     regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d{1,2}:\\d{2} (AM|PM)"
                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                            error:&error];
NSString *str = @"Monday thru Friday 8:00 AM - 7:30 PM";
NSArray *m = [regex matchesInString:str
                            options:0
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, I know... That's the way the regex APIs are in cocoa. I wish I could write it in fewer lines.

Comment: @H2CO3 Regular expressions are good at this. IMO they are much easier to read and reason than custom made code like you proposed (which assumes no digit before time, time separated by dash etc.). It specifically says "Find something in the form X:XX AM or X:XX PM".

Comment: I'm seriously disappointed that this got 6 upvotes whereas my nice and simple (and earlier) solution didn't get **any**... Where you programmers have put your aesthetic sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about first go by replacing occurrences of some strings.

So use the `[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Monday" withString: @""];`

remove all the days and probably the "thru" string.

Then you're left  with the hours. Don't forget to watch for space characters.

Hope this helps.